# GraphQL type Nesting and cyclic Dependenciies on Types

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

here i have 3 Types

**JobType**

**EmployerType**

**SeekerType**

A `job` will have only one `Employer` who created it

```
const JobsType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'JobsType',
    fields: {
        jobsId: {
            type: GraphQLID,
            resolve: obj => obj._id,
        },
        title: { type: GraphQLString },
        description: { type: GraphQLString },
        experience: { type: GraphQLString },
        position: { type: GraphQLString },
        openings: { type: GraphQLInt },
        employer: {
            type: EmployerType
            resolve: () => // somedata here
        }
    },
});
```

An `Employer` can create multiple `jobs` so

```
const EmployerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'EmployerType',
    fields: {
        userId: {
            type: GraphQLID,
            resolve: obj => obj._id,
        },
        company: { type: GraphQLString },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
        industry: { type: ENUM.IndustryType },
        ownerShip: { type: ENUM.OwnerShipType },
        website: { type: GraphQLString },
        jobs: {
            type: JobsType,
            resolve: (obj) => // some data to resolve
        }
    },
});
```

A `seeker` can apply to many `jobs` so,

```
const SeekerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'SeekerType',
    fields: {
        userId: {
            type: GraphQLID,
            resolve: obj => obj._id,
        },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
        firstName: { type: GraphQLString },
        lastName: { type: GraphQLString },
        education: { type: GraphQLString },
        address: { type: GraphQLString },
        jobs: {
            type: JobsType,
            resolve: (obj) => // some data to resolve
        }
    },
});
```

so here it seems to have multiple and cyclic dependencies on the `GraphQLObjectType`

`Jobs` contains `EmployerType`, and again `EmployerType` contains `jobs`, where as `job` have again `EmployerType`

so like this

```
{
    job {
        jobId,
        jobTitle,
        employer {
            userId,
            company,
            email,
            job {
                jobId, 
                jobTitle,
                employer {
                    userId,
                    company,
                    email
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is not the correct way as the dependencies goes deeper and deeper

same for `SeekerType` too

```
{
    seeker {
        userId,
        email,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        job {
            jobId,
            title,
            description,
            employer {
                userId,
                company,
                email,
                job {
                    jobId,
                    title,
                    employer {
                        userId,
                        company
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what might the solution for this

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: mine question is about maitaining a multiple custom `GraphQLObjectType`  and providing them related data